# In TypeScript how to understand which decorators are used?

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

Right now in TypeScript there are 2 types of decorators - the legacy and stage 3 ones.

```
// legacy decorator type
const legacyDecorator: PropertyDecorator;

// modern decorator type
const modernDecorator: <This, Value>(value: unknown, context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext<This, Result>) => void;
```

I want to create an NPM library which can used with both of decorators. But I have a problem of defining which version of decorators developer used.

I'd like to use some type like this

```
const myDecorator: ChooseType<
  PropertyDecorator,
  <This, Value>(value: unknown, context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext<This, Result>) => void,
>;
```

This way I could provide more specific types for the new decorators, but remain legacy decorators work too.

Is it possible in any way to achieve it? Maybe not with the generic type, you can tell any possible solution.